# is there any way to train yolov4 model without GPU?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolov4

i am continously facing an error "connect without GPU".i am tranning a yolov4 model and i want to resolve this issue to continue further.

Comment: Do either of these previous posts help? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56520802) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347543/can-we-use-cpu-instead-of-gpu-to-train-custome-yolo-model-for-object-detection)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.